# IPset using Cloud Database

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, aws

I am currently looking at implementing a Raspberry pi Security Device Acting as My WiFi Hub using IPset to Allow or Deny Ip Addresses inbound or outbound.
Is it possible to have an Amazon RDS or any Cloud Database with a Database Table Full of Blacklisted IP Addresses and have those bad hosts being pushed down onto my Linux WiFi Server?

So when I add more BlackList IP addresses this will automatically update my IPset Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, all such things are possible but quite a bit of work.

1. Create a Linux instance running in AWS.  For security considerations you'd better give it a fixed *elastic* ip address.
2. Set up a database on it.  You could use the AWS RDS service but that seems a lot of overkill for what you want so probably just install *postgresql* via your package manager.
3. Set up an interface for updating it with blacklisted ip addresses.  Remember that you want to intake both additions and subtractions from blacklists.  If you only intake additions you'll eventually just have a blacklist with **everything** in it!
4. For it to be useful you'd also have to set up some sort of automated feed to that interface: so security and configuration considerations apply.  You want to make sure you're getting legitimate feeds and not some spoofed version thereof. There are many sources: each with it's own interface such as *ZIP* files of their latest lists to FTP or web API feeds.
5. Use AWS SNS to periodically publish updates to the data base to your WiFi hub via HTTPS/HTTP *POST*s or whatever it's easiest for it to digest.
6. Configure the WiFi hub to accept the updates and reconfigure itself.  Again there are security considerations as you don't want to accept updates from just anywhere.

A fun project and by the time you're finished you'll have all sorts of database, API, and AWS skills under your hat/resumé.